# Custom server controls - how to get intellisense support and rid the xhtml error?

Tags: asp.net, intellisense, custom-server-controls

I have created a custom control which takes a custom template. But there is no intellisense support and there is this xhtml error. [image: Markup of custom control]

I have checked some questions; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307514/custom-intellisense-for-server-controls) post says we have to get it by default. However I haven't been getting it. Am I missing something to do?

Here is how the code looks like:

**Server Control:**

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomTemplateControl runat=server></{0}:CustomTemplateControl>")]
[Description("My Custom Template Control")]
public class CustomTemplateControl : WebControl
{
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(CustomTemplateItem))]
    public ITemplate CustomHeader { get; set; }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        if (CustomHeader != null)
        {
            CustomHeader.InstantiateIn(this);
        }
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ClientID);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Label);

        //base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
    }
```

**Template:**

```
public class CustomTemplateItem : Control, INamingContainer
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a schema file that describes your custom control and reference that schema file in whatever VS project. you use it in.

xhtml doesn't like uppercase characters.  Probably would have to change the custom controls Attributes with all lowercase characters.